# Generating a Code-Coverage Test Report for iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, code-coverage

> Code coverage in Xcode is a testing option supported by LLVM. When you
>   enable code coverage, LLVM instruments the code to gather coverage
>   data based on the frequency that methods and functions are called. The
>   code coverage option can collect data to report on tests of
>   correctness and of performance, whether unit tests or UI tests.

I would like to generate a code-coverage report via Xcode.

I've looked at gcovr http://gcovr.com. 
...or is it more prudent to generate a report via xcodebuild?

Is there a tutorial or guide to generating a report via Xcode 8+?

Answer (score 2):

There is `-enableCodeCoverage YES` option for `xcodebuild`. You can easily see possibilities of `xcodebuild` command by typing `xcodebuild --help`.

Here are Apple guildelines on code coverage usage: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/07-code_coverage.html

You can even see the coverage report directly from Xcode.

Comment: Is there a way to create a generate report for distribution (PDF,HTML, etc.)?

Comment: there is lcov tool to generate HTML reports (http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php). To install it use command line brew install lcov

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee please don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you.